# How can i create a custom artisan command for 'php artisan'?

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

I have created a file named `PACommand.php` in `app\Console\Commands\PACommand.php`.
I want to create basically a shortcut called `pa` for `php artisan`. But I am not where to go in handle method.

PACommand.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;

class PACommand extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'pa';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'php artisan command';

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        // return Command::SUCCESS;

        Artisan::call("php artisan");
        $this->info(Artisan::output());

        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't make `pa` a shortcut for `php artisan` this way. (Your command would be invoked via `php artisan pa`; no go.) You'd need to do that in your shell; look up bash aliases. https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-create-bash-aliases/

Comment: @ceejayoz If I do that in shell, does that affect only this laravel application or does that affect on any laravel app I create in the future as well?

Comment: Write your global `pa` command in a way that it searches for the artisan file in the current directory and then invokes the global `php` command. This way, it will be applicable to every project, but you must be inside the project directory at the time of invocation, just like in the case of the `php artisan` command.

Comment: You cannot affect shell from the application, only from system. Only way for you - make docker image with alias and use this image in all projects. Or make shell script and add to composer autoload script, but this is not good approach.

Comment: @saddysad It's just an alias; using it works the same as typing the full thing out. `pa` would work anywhere `php artisan` would work; it would not work anywhere `php artisan` would not.

Comment: If you are using Linux there's an alternative where you can rename your `artisan` file into `pa` and make it executable (e.g. `chmod +x pa`) then you can use it as `./pa <command>` .